# Coefficients of Fourier Cosine Series expansion

Tags: fourier-series

I'm trying to prove to myself that

a<sub>0</sub> = $\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^Lf$<sub>e</sub>$(x)dx$ = $\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^Lf$<sub>e</sub>$(x)dx$

but I keep getting a<sub>0</sub> = 0.

This is my logic at the moment. If:

$f$<sub>e</sub>$(x)$ = $f(x)$ for $0<x<L$

And

$f$<sub>e</sub>$(x)$ = $f$<sub>e</sub>$(-x)$ for all x then:

$\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^Lf$<sub>e</sub>$(x)dx$ = $\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^0f$<sub>e</sub>$(x)dx+\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^Lf$<sub>e</sub>(x)dx

= $\frac{1}{L}\int_{L}^0f$<sub>e</sub>$(-x)dx+\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^Lf$<sub>e</sub>(x)dx

= $\frac{1}{L}\int_{L}^0f$<sub>e</sub>$(x)dx+\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^Lf$<sub>e</sub>(x)dx

= $\frac{2}{L}\int_{L}^Lf$<sub>e</sub>$(x)dx = 0$

I've tried doing this a few different ways and always get this result and I really can't find where I'm going wrong, any and all help appreciated.

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 1):

In your next to your last step, it looks like you try to make the substitution

$$x' = -x$$

But you forgot to include a negative sign because

$$dx' = -dx$$